# Error while trying trying to use oauth2 / AccountManagerFuture to authenticate with Google

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, accountmanager

An android app i'm working on uses Google oauth to authenticate users (via AccountManager).

It's been working fine until yesterday and now whenever the app tries to authenticate and get a google auth token I get the following error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H8xT.png

Logcat shows the following (email removed):

```
I/GLSUser ( 1478): GLS error: RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED xxx@yyy.com oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
V/GoogleLoginService( 1478): Returning error intent with: ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gsf.login/com.google.android.gsf.login.LoginActivity}
I/ActivityManager(  456): START {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.google.android.gsf.login/.LoginActivity (has extras) u=0} from pid 3967
I/ActivityManager(  456): START {cmp=com.google.android.gsf.login/.ShowErrorActivity (has extras) u=0} from pid 1478
I/qtaguid ( 1478): Tagging socket 52 with tag dc4e7700000000(14438007) for uid -1 failed errno=-13
I/NetworkManagementSocketTagger( 1478): tagSocketFd(52, 14438007, -1) failed with errno-13
W/GLSActivity( 1478): GAIA ERROR WITH NO RESOURCE STRING Unknown
I/ActivityManager(  456): Displayed com.google.android.gsf.login/.ShowErrorActivity: +69ms (total +92ms)
```

Has anybody seen this RATE_LIMIT_EXCEEDED error before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, but maybe you are sending too many request? Do you have a background service, etc? Try with a different account and maybe consider using Google Play Services, it might be able to at least handle this better.

Comment: Thanks Nikolay. It turns out I had a problem in my code that was requesting a key from Google twice in very short succession. Once i'd fixed that logic error it all sprang back into life.

o/t: Keep up the fantastic blog posts - I've been following your blog for a while and some of your posts on AES and securely using the keystore have been a huge help to me.

Comment: Glad you find them useful, I've got a new one coming up. Somewhat related to this question. Stay tuned :)